# uploading file on server response 500 internal server error in codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload

my code is working fine on localhost but when i uploading file to server i got this error 500 internal server error.

my code is here:

upload method

```
 public function do_upload($fieldname)
{
    $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types']        = 'jpg|png';
    $config['max_size']             = 10000;
    /*$config['max_width']            = 1024;
    $config['max_height']           = 768;*/
    //echo '<pre>'; print_r($config); exit;  //this array responding Ok but the issue is in the bottom codintion.

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload($fieldname))
    {

        $error = array('condition'=>'error', 'error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        return $error;
    }
    else
    {

        $data = array('condition'=>'success', 'upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        return $data;

    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: A 500 generally means theres an error hiding behind it and that the 500 was only served to prevent any sensitive information being shown. Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL)` and see what the actual error is.

Comment: `/uploads/` may not be writable

Comment: error 500 internal server error.It means error at your `ajax` calling.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
```

Try using the full path: e.g. `/var/www/public_html/uploads`

```
$config['upload_path']          = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/uploads/';
```

Also ensure your `/uploads/` directory is writable

Comment: Thank you @zanderwar, i try all these methods but didn't get any positive response.

Comment: Ok, you'll need to track down your `error_log` that PHP produces on Fatal Errors.